# jQuery or Javascript logarithmic repulsion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I know that is a funky-sounding title, but I couldn't think of a better one for my needs.  Also, this is a lot of text, but just visiting the link below will explain 90% of what I need.

BACKGROUND:
I am designing a price-range slider for an e-commerce site.  An early prototype can be found here: http://mcdev3com00.web705.discountasp.net/collision-test.htm.

It may be helpful to visit this page before reading on.  If you slide the left handle towards the right, it is almost accomplishing my goal and seeing that will make the rest easier to understand.

GOAL:
I am trying to design the slider so that the information divs located at the top of the handle will repel each other logarithmic-ally the closer they come to each other.

The purpose is to allow the display of the price information without the divs containing that information colliding when the handles have only a little space between them.

DETAILS:
So in other words, as the left handle slides to the right, the div containing the dollar value on the top of it should at first slide in small increments towards the left of the lower part of the handle, but as the whole left handle comes closer to the right handle, the increments become larger until the right-side of the div containing the price (upper part of handle) is flush with the right side of the lower part of the handle.

RULES/CONSTRAINTS:

1. There must always be at least a few pixels of space between left and right handles, they can not overlap.
2. When there is only the minimum distance between handles, the RIGHT SIDE of the left handle's price container must be flush with the RIGHT SIDE of the lower part of the left handle and the LEFT SIDE of the right handle's price container must be flush with the LEFT SIDE of the lower part of the right handle.
3. When the left handle is as far left as it can go (x=0%) the LEFT side of the upper div (price container) must be flush with the left side of the lower part of the handle.
4. When the right handle is as far right as it can go (x=100%) the RIGHT side of the upper div (price container) must be flush with the right side of the lower part of the handle.
5. Moving one handle will move it's own price container and the price container of the opposite handle, as long as doing so doesn't violate rules 1-4.

VARIABLES:
 1. Location of left handle
 2. Location of right handle
 3. Width of left handle price container
 4. Width of right handle price container
 5. Total width of slider control
 6. Distance between left and right handles

PROGRESS SO FAR:
The left handle (as you can see by visiting the link above) is *almost* functioning properly.  The problem is that if you slide it almost all of the way over to the right, the price container bounces farther to the left than it is supposed to according to the if/then logic and that is baffling me.

The right handle really isn't functioning well at all.

Any help here would be GREATLY appreciated.  I have been up all night trying to beat a deadline with a client and I am just hitting a wall.

Many thanks!

### PS-The formula that should be working the magic is called "avoidCollision":

```
function avoidCollision(handle0, handle1) {

var lPrice = $("#test-left-handle-info"); //price container left
var rPrice = $("#test-right-handle-info"); //price container right
var lPriceWidth = lPrice.outerWidth(); //width of left price container
var rPriceWidth = rPrice.outerWidth(); //width of right price container
var lPriceOffsetLeft = (lPrice.offset().left); //document-level LEFT-EDGE position of left price container 
var lPriceOffsetRight = lPriceOffsetLeft + lPriceWidth;  //document-level RIGHT-EDGE position of left price container 
var rPriceOffsetLeft = rPrice.offset().left; //document-level LEFT-EDGE position of right price container 

var lContainer = $("#handle0"); //containing element for left-side price container and lower handle.
var rContainer = $("#handle1"); //containing element for right-side price container and lower handle.

var tW = $("#slider-range").width();   //total width of slider
var hw = $("#handle0").outerWidth(); //handle width
var hHw = ($("#handle0").outerWidth()) / 2; // half handle width

var cPosL = (lContainer.offset().left); //left edge of left handle
var cPosLre = cPosL + hw; //right edge of left handle
var cPosR = rContainer.offset().left; //left edge of right handle

//distance between handles as a percentage of total slider width:
var dis = ((cPosR - cPosLre) / tW);
//inverse of "dis" or remainder out of 100%:
var disInv = 1 - dis;

var mlt = -1; //multiplier to get the correct movement value (i.e. negative value to move left along the x-axis)
//if(cPosLRE < cPosLPrev){disInv = dis;} ?????
var lMove = ((lPriceWidth * disInv) * mlt) + hHw + 1; //css "left" value of lPrice
var rMove = rPriceWidth * disInv; //css "left" value of rPrice


//this is just helpful info for debugging:
$("#infoDivDiv").html("<br/><br/><strong>lInfoPosRE:</strong> " + lPriceOffsetRight + "<br/><strong>cPosLRE:</strong> " + cPosLre + "<br/><strong>lMove:</strong> " + lMove + "<br/><strong>lInfoWidth:</strong> " + lPriceWidth + "<br/><strong>Hw:</strong> " + hw + "<br/><strong>lInfoPos:</strong> " + lPriceOffsetLeft + "<br/><strong>cPosL:</strong> " + cPosL + "<br/><strong>cPosLPrev:</strong> " + cPosLPrev + "<br/><strong>cPosR:</strong> " + cPosR + "<br/><strong>rInfoPos:</strong> " + rPriceOffsetLeft + "<br/><strong>cPosRPrev:</strong> " + cPosRPrev);


//here is where the magic happens, also where I am lost.
if ((((lPriceOffsetRight >= cPosLre) && (lPriceOffsetLeft >= cPosL)) || (cPosLre < cPosLPrev)) && (cPosL > 10)) { 
    lPrice.css({ left: lMove });
}

if ((((rPriceOffsetLeft <= cPosR)) || (cPosR > cPosRPrev)) && (cPosR < (tW - 10))) {
    rPrice.css({ left: rMove });
}

cPosLPrev = cPosLre; //assign the current value to the "previous" container to be used in the next run so we know in which direction we are moving.
cPosRPrev = cPosR; //assign the current value to the "previous" container to be used in the next run so we know in which direction we are moving.
```

### }

Comment: What exactly do you mean by logarithmically? Can't you just align one on the left and the other on the right?

Comment: You mean just flip the alignment if the two handles are close to each other?  If so, then the answer is yes.  However, the client wants a smooth effect sort of like I already have on the left handle.  They already have an iPhone app that does just that and this needs to match.  Thanks!

Comment: there are a number of libraries that will do this for you: d3.js, springy, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather not delve into your code, but I can see the steps you need to get there:

1. Find the midway point between the two sliders
2. Find the proportion the sliders are between their home position and the middle point.
3. This proportion indicates where the label should go. A value of 1 means all the way to one side, and a value of 0 all the way to the other.

I don't see how you plan to involve logarithms...

---

Here's some pseudocode:

```
var leftPos, rightPos; //Get these somehow
var leftHome = 0;
var rightHome = 1;
var midpoint = (leftPos + rightPos) / 2;

var leftProportion = (leftPos - leftHome) / (midpoint - leftHome);
var rightProportion = (rightPos - rightHome) / (midpoint - rightHome);

if leftProportion == 0
    put label flush with left edge
up unto leftProportion == 1
    put label flush with right edge

if rightProportion == 0
    put label flush with right edge
up unto rightProportion == 1
    put label flush with left edge
```

Comment: It is a logarithmic slider (or exponential, depending on how you look at it). As you slide the slider to the right, it increases the value exponentially. I think that's all he means.

Comment: Eric, it is already logarithmic by its very nature.  The "messy" code is a prototype and not all that messy anyway.  I appreciate your proposed solution but it tosses the client's requests out of the window which I won't do.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: In what way does this toss the request out the window? This gives a linear response, which is probably what you wanted anyway. The label would move smoothly from one side to the other. And no, it's not logarithmic. There is no logarithmic function in your code, so how can it be?

Comment: Thanks Peter!  My tired brain just couldn't verbalize it succinctly at the moment.

Comment: @Eric- Thanks again, but the reason I can't use your solution (as I understand it) is that it simply flips the price container to one side or another of the handle.  I already had this solution in place ages ago.  It is not what the client wants.  I aim to please ;).  Thanks again though, seriously.

Comment: @Matt: That's not what this solution is.

Comment: Eric, thanks for the psuedocode.  I will give it a try.  I am going on no sleep last night so possible that I am failing to understand your meaning.  I will just try and code it up.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well Eric, I just took a look at your proposed solution with fresh eyes after a shower and shave, and it won't work for me.  I am not arguing that it functions to meet the same end, but it is the means that don't work--there is no animated sliding effect of the price container.  Also, I would appreciate if you remove the "messy code" comment.  It was unnecessary and unhelpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew: Comment removed. Sorry. I don't see what the issue with the price container is though.

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/7tghw/) a demo that will accomplish the last 4 lines of the code.